python plotly x axis dates show all ticks
I'm using plotly.graph_objects to generate a html with data embedded.
Although I am really pleased with the library, I cannot make it display all my x-axis ticks in some scenarios, as shown below.

Yet, if I zoom in, I get all the ticks (desired behaviour)
Question is: Is there any way I can enforce plotly to display all ticks, when they refer to months? (Displaying all ticks regarding days while displaying one whole year would be too much ticks)
My current code is:
import pandas               as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

list_data_mb    =   [
                        ('2023-01-01',10 ,'dat') , ('2023-01-15',15 ,'dat'),('2023-01-01',10 ,'ind') , ('2023-01-15',15 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-02-01',20 ,'dat') , ('2023-02-15',25 ,'dat'),('2023-02-01',20 ,'ind') , ('2023-02-15',25 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-03-01',30 ,'dat') , ('2023-03-15',35 ,'dat'),('2023-03-01',30 ,'ind') , ('2023-03-15',35 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-04-01',40 ,'dat') , ('2023-04-15',45 ,'dat'),('2023-04-01',40 ,'ind') , ('2023-04-15',45 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-05-01',50 ,'dat') , ('2023-05-15',55 ,'dat'),('2023-05-01',50 ,'ind') , ('2023-05-15',55 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-06-01',60 ,'dat') , ('2023-06-15',65 ,'dat'),('2023-06-01',60 ,'ind') , ('2023-06-15',65 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-07-01',70 ,'dat') , ('2023-07-15',75 ,'dat'),('2023-07-01',70 ,'ind') , ('2023-07-15',75 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-08-01',80 ,'dat') , ('2023-08-15',85 ,'dat'),('2023-08-01',80 ,'ind') , ('2023-08-15',85 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-09-01',90 ,'dat') , ('2023-09-15',95 ,'dat'),('2023-09-01',90 ,'ind') , ('2023-09-15',95 ,'ind'),
                        ('2023-10-01',100,'dat') , ('2023-10-15',102,'dat'),('2023-10-01',100,'ind') , ('2023-10-15',102,'ind'),
                        ('2023-11-01',104,'dat') , ('2023-11-15',106,'dat'),('2023-11-01',104,'ind') , ('2023-11-15',106,'ind'),
                        ('2023-12-01',108,'dat') , ('2023-12-15',110,'dat'),('2023-12-01',108,'ind') , ('2023-12-15',108,'ind'),
                        ('2024-01-01',112,'dat') , ('2024-01-15',114,'dat'),('2024-01-01',112,'ind') , ('2024-01-15',114,'ind'),
                    ]
df              =   pd.DataFrame(list_data_mb,columns=['date','size','tbs'])
df['date']      =   pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")

data            =   [go.Bar(name=tbs, x=dfg['date'], y=dfg['size']) for tbs,dfg in df.groupby(by='tbs')]
fig             =   go.Figure(data)
fig.update_layout(
                    barmode     =   'stack', 
                    title       =   'Tablespaces size over time', 
                    xaxis_title =   'Date', 
                )
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeslider_visible=True,
    tickmode='array', #linear: too many values. And for "1d", it will not display hours
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1, label="1d" , step="day",   stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="1m" , step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6, label="6m" , step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="1y" , step="year",  stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year",  stepmode="todate"  ),
            dict(                      step="all"                       )
        ])
    )
)
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='white')
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='white')
fig.write_html("./aux_0.html")


By default, the number of ticks is adjusted automatically according to the zoom range and the space available (tickmode='auto'), and the layout width is automatically set according to the device screen size. We can still use dtick to force plotly to display every month :
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='linear', tick0=df['date'].min(), dtick='M1')


...but setting a linear tickmode will disable the dynamic adjustment of the ticks when updating the zoom range, which is probably not what you want.
We can also manually adjust the tick formatting according to specific (predefined arbitrarily) zoom ranges using tickformatstops, but unfortunately we can't do that for dtick.
